# Dash plotly data table Fixed column with merge_duplicate_headers=True causes scrollbar to scroll beyond the table width

Tags: python, datatable, plotly-dash

I'm observing the following issue:

[image]

Following is the code:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

table = dash_table.DataTable(
    columns=[
        {"name": ["", "Year"], "id": "year"},
        {"name": ["City", "Montreal"], "id": "montreal"},
        {"name": ["City", "Toronto"], "id": "toronto"},
        {"name": ["City", "Ottawa"], "id": "ottawa"},
        {"name": ["City", "Vancouver"], "id": "vancouver"},
        {"name": ["Climate", "Temperature"], "id": "temp"},
        {"name": ["Climate", "Humidity"], "id": "humidity"}
    ],
    data=[
        {
            "year": i,
            "montreal": i * 10,
            "toronto": i * 100,
            "ottawa": i * -1,
            "vancouver": i * -10,
            "temp": i * -100,
            "humidity": i * 5,
        }
        for i in range(10)],
    merge_duplicate_headers=True,
    fixed_columns={'headers': True, 'data': 1},
    style_table={
        'minWidth': '100%'
    }
)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='table', children=table),
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This issue arises only with `merge_duplicate_headers=True` and I have to use merge_duplicate_headers.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Firefox and Chromium. Any chance there is a custom CSS in the assets sub-folder? Does this happen to you in multiple browsers?